# How to pull data from Paginated JSON

Tags: javascript, json, pagination, fetch

I have say 300 items 10 show to a page. The page loads the JSON data and is limited to 10 (this cannot be changed)

I want to scrub through the 30 odd pages pulling each item and listing it.

```
url.com/api/some-name?page=1 etc
```

The script ideally will use the above URL as a rule and scrub through increments of 1 until all 10 from each page is populated.

Can this be done? How would I go about it? Any advice or assistance to this would help me greatly in learning and looking at methods people suggest.

```
const getInfo = async function(pageNo) {
const jsonUrl = "https://website.com/api/some-title";

  let actualUrl = jsonUrl + `?page=${pageNo}`;
  let jsonResults = await fetch(actualUrl).then(response => {
    return response.json();
  });
  return jsonResults;
};
const getEntireList = async function(pageNo) {
  const results = await getInfo(pageNo);
  console.log("Retreiving data from API for page:" + pageNo);
  if (results.length > 0) {
    return results.concat(await getEntireList(pageNo));
  } else {
    return results;
  }
};
(async () => {
  const entireList = await getEntireList();
  console.log(entireList);
})();
```

Comment: Share with us what have you tried to solve this issue.

Comment: Hi @IslamElshobokshy I have updated the post with what I have so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see some issues in your code.

1. the initial call to getEntireList() should be initialised with the index of first page, maybe like `const entireList = await getEntireList(1);`
2. The page number will need to be incremented at some point.
3. `results.concat()` probably won't have the desired effect. `json()` returns an object, list, or value (depending on the server) and `results` will be one of those type. `concat()` operates on strings; so calling `json()` is (at best) redundant.